# Data Upload Error for QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, qgis-cloud

I'm just taking a stab at QGIS Cloud to investigate it for a potential client, and I am pleased with the functionality of the web-viewer based on the sample maps. Although I cannot upload my own data.

While attempting to upload a very small layer (3 points) I keep recieving the same error message and I was hoping someone on here may be able to elaborate on what may be the problem. [image: ERROR SCREEN]

Comment: Is there a field with the data type long? If so delete that field and see if it workd

Comment: @lolcat, I checked all the fields and none are long type. Thank you for the help though.